# My Span element is not responding to css on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

My spans with hover work on a tablet (my iPad) and desktop computer. However, on my phone the CSS styling disappears, while I understand that hover effects don't really "work" on phones/touch screens but part of the CSS is hiding the span when not hovered over.

HTML:

```
<section id="proj1">

    <a href="EJ.html">
        <img id="c" src="img/rjcover.jpeg">
    </a>

    <span id="one">
        Envisioning Justice 
        <br>
        <br>
        May 2020

    </span>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
span {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: 'Darker Grotesque', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: #FAD714;
    color: white;
    width: 75%;
    margin-top: -190px;
}

#proj1:hover #one {
    display: block;
}

#proj2:hover #two {
    display: block;
}

#proj3:hover #three {
    display: block;
}

#proj4:hover #four {
    display: block;
}
```

http://iam.colum.edu/students/riley.jakusik/designbyriley/

that is the link to it live.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code for your element?

Comment: i updated the post as well. Sorry for the confusion I am new

Comment: What do you want it to do for mobile sizes?  Always show the banner?  There's technically no css error happening.  For the most part, on a mobile device, there is no way to hover, so the span's `display: none;` is never negated.  In order to help, we need to know what the desired behavior is.  Sadly, it can't be, "make `:hover` work on mobile devices".  If the device doesn't support it, then it doesn't support it.  It needs to be something like, "show banner on touch" or "always show the banner on devices without `:hover`."

Answer (score 0):

You should always take into consideration what will create the best user-experience. If you are setting display:none on your span element and then displaying that element on hover you are creating a situation for users who are on a device that does not support the hover state that will not be the best experience for them. One possible solution would be to use a [hover media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover). This way you can specify styling that will apply to users that are on a device that supports that feature, and if not you can specify a fallback for users that are on a device that does not:

```
@media (hover: hover) {
    #one {
      display: none;
    }
    #proj1:hover #one {
      display: block;
    }
}
```

The CSS [@supports rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports) will also be a useful tool to familiarize yourself with.

**EDIT:** And thank you to @SandeshSapkota for pointing out that hover state is still supported in many mobile devices, but I think that it is useful to familiarize yourself with the aforementioned hover media query as it is a useful tool in many situations. A better approach to your issue may be to instead implement a media query that tests for viewport width, and if it is smaller than say 641px, which is the value that [Foundation](https://get.foundation/) uses to detect mobile devices then just show the span element by default:

```
@media (max-width: 641px) {
  #one {
    display: block;
  }
```

This query means that if the device in question has a viewport width at a maximum of 641px then apply the styles.

Comment: so this is how we restrict a `hover` state of an element for mobile devices which we usually apply for desktop? but `hover` state still works on the mobile right! but in mobile, there is no such thing as hover out in desktop when not hovering in the area, In mobile hover state of the element will be removed only when we click somewhere else.

Comment: @SandeshSapkota this is a good point. Probably a better solution would be to utilize a media query to test viewport width and apply the hover state styling, especially when toggling the display of an element on hover. I will update my proposed solution.